# How to approximate damped harmonic under random forcing

Tags: integration, random, convolution

Given motion in response to random forcing, can a "simple" function be used to estimate future motion.  Starting with the damped harmonic oscillator, we can write

$${d^2 \over {dt^2}} h(t) + 2 \zeta \omega_n {d \over dt} h(t) 
+ \omega_n^2 h(t) = { F(t) \over m} $$

This can be rewritten in state transition form as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    { d \over dt} h(t) \\
    h(t)       
\end{bmatrix}
=
 {e^{-\zeta \omega_n t}
\over \omega_d} 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \omega_d  cos(\omega_d  t) + \zeta \omega_n sin(\omega_d  t) 
& sin(\omega_d t) \\
    -\omega_n^2  sin(\omega_d  \tau)  
& \omega_d  cos(\omega_d  t) - \zeta \omega_n sin(\omega_d  t)     
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    { d \over dt} h(0) \\
    h(0)       
\end{bmatrix}
\\
+
{1 \over {m \omega_d}}
\int_0^\tau e^{-\zeta \omega_n t} 
\begin{bmatrix}
    -sin(\omega_d \tau) \\
    - \omega_d  cos(\omega_d  \tau) + \zeta \omega_n sin(\omega_d  \tau)       
\end{bmatrix}
F(t-\tau)  d \tau 
$$

How to approximate the integral term.  The goal is to use previous motion data to estimate the parameters $\omega$ and $\zeta$ and generate an approximation for F and then forecast future data.  It may be simpler to assume that F was harmonic. The convolution integral can probably be used to split the integral into two manageable parts, which is what I was trying to do, before posting this question.  An alternate approach would be to assume F is a sum of a small number of harmonics, and fit F to the data.

If we assume the forcing is of the form 
$$C_i sin(Omega_i t + phi_i)$$
the a closed form solution can be found.

mupad commands

```
assume(z>0.001 and z<.3), assume(omega>0 and omega<.25)
IVP := ode({h''(t) +2*z*omega*h'(t)+ omega*omega*h(t)=1/m*C_i*sin(Omega_i*t+phi_i), h(0) = h0, h'(0) = dh0}, h(t))
sol := solve(IVP)
```

I'm not sure how to simplify the solution further, but this solution could be used to estimate the future values of h from initial values of h and dh.

Comment: You haven't defined F().

Comment: F() is a random variable, with non-stationary statistics.  But, I'm willing to approximate F as the sum of a small number of harmonics.   Maybe I should write out the rest of the problem, to give more insight into what I'm asking here.

Comment: OK, I've updated the question so it makes more sense.